# Setting ISAPI and CGI restrictions to Allowed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am trying to follow some instructions for an `IIS` setup which says:

> Double click Server node in IIS (not web site node). Ensure ISAPI and
>   CGI Restrictions property setting for  ASP.NET 2.0 and 4.0 is set to
>   ‘Allowed’

After spending some time finally I was able to find `ISPAI and CGI Restrictions`. But I cannot find the place to set something to Allowed on it per instructions.

Should I enable something else first before it shows up?

This is how far I got:

[image]

Comment: Click on the `Open Feature` Link

Comment: @JamesP I did but there was nothing in it

Comment: Then I am guessing you don't have the `ISAPI Extensions` features installed for IIS - https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/isapicgirestriction/add